# Сбор всех SQL statements, выполняющихся в Oracle DB 12с

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Приветствую. Необходимо видеть все SQL выражения, которые выполняются (выполнялись) во всех сессиях. Перерыл кучу информации. Везде предлагают решения, которые подходят только для отслеживания в конкретной сессии. Можно ли как-то добиться желаемого? Мне нужно видеть список с именами пользователей и текстом SQL выражения, который пользователь выполняет. Заранее спсибо.

Comment: [Oracle Audit Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_admin.htm#DBSEG1026) (`alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL='db,extended' scope=spfile;`) ?

Comment: @MaxU А можно ли как-то вытащить нужную мне информацию в C# коде?

Comment: Если у вас есть DBA роль и есть возможность перезагрузить всю БД (для включения аудита), то да, сможете

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, буду ковырять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** можно воспользоваться новой "фичей" (Oracle 12.1+) - [Unified Audit Data Trail](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/oracle_database_12c_new_unified) которая объединяет в себе:

- SYS.AUD$ for the database audit trail,
- SYS.FGA_LOG$ for fine-grained auditing,
- DVSYS.AUDIT_TRAIL$ for Oracle Database Vault, Oracle Label Security,
- and so on.

Она также позволяет делать аудит по условиям - [примеры использования](http://oracle12cexplorer.blogspot.de/2014/07/unified-auditing-in-oracle-database-12c.html)

По утверждениям Oracle они переработали движок для Unified Audit Data Trail и теперь он должен быть более быстрым и более производительным...

---

**Предыдущий ответ:**

Воспользуйтесь [Oracle AUDIT Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_admin.htm#DBSEG1026):

[Включение](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-BD86F593-B606-4367-9FB6-8DAB2E47E7FA.htm#REFRN10006):

```
SQL> alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL=db, extended scope=spfile;
```

После этого надо перезагрузить всю базу...

Включение аудита для пользователя "TEST":

```
SQL> audit all statements by TEST;
```

Просмотр аудита:

```
SQL> select * from sys.aud$ where userid='TEST';
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Один вопрос остался: а можно ли как-то из этой выборки оставить только те строки, в которых SQL выражения сгенерированы пользователем, а не системой? А то слишком много лишних запросов.

Comment: @Denis Lolik надо помнить, что включение аудита очень сильно просаживает производительность БД